# Low performance on MongoDB aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server

I gather events from devices and store each of those events inside a mongoDB. I have a total of 150k records.

When I use an aggregation operation to get documents sorted by date and grouped by a specific field, it takes 10 seconds for the NodeJs server to respond (using Postman) on a localhost machine.

Here is the document model :

```
    {
            "_id": "5a0dc8528b7f1f00102b5006",          
            "version": "0.2.0",
            "timestamp": "2017-08-25T03:49:37.000Z",
            "deviceId": "00:1E:C0:41:06:82",
            "param1": 1,
            "param2": 2,
            "param3": 3,
            "param4": 4,
            "param5": 5,
    }
```

Here is the method I use :

```
EventSchema.statics.getLastEventForAllDevices = function () {

    return this.aggregate([
        {
            "$sort": {
                "timestamp": -1
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$deviceId",
                lastEvent: {
                    $last: "$$ROOT"
                }
            }
        }
    ]).allowDiskUse(true);;

};
```

Its taking 10 seconds for only 150k. I expect to get millions of record in the next two months so I fear that it will just timeout.

What is wrong ? Bad mongodb call ? Or server performance to low ?

Comment: Do you have an index on `timestamp`?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/ <-- You are talking about this I guess. No, I do not have index on timestamp. But how does it work exactly ? Should I call createIndex each time I'm making a request ?

Comment: even when creating indexes on timestamp, it still taking a lot of time...

Comment: You shouldn't be calling it each time you make the request.  Just one time, or you can use something like Robomogo to create the index.